# how to replace masked image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Image should be replaced without pasting image or grouping to the below as grouping remains the previous image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the mask (from the blue image) onto the layer with the green image:

1. Select the layer with the green image
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the mask from the blue layer
3. <kbd>Click</kbd> the **Add Vector Mask** icon at the bottom of the layers palette (that will create a mask that matches the first one.)
4. Hide or delete the layer with the blue image.

Answer (score 1):

- Copy the green image to new layer.
- Click and drag the mask from the blue image layer to the green image layer
- Delete blue image layer.

Answer (score 0):

I just did cntrl+click to select the image, the pressed delete.  I then copied my new image and pasted it into the layer where I did the delete.  Then I just had to drag and size it to taste. The mask remained as originally set.